# Blocking ads on router indirectly?

Tags: router, hosts

I have a TL-WR941ND dlink router and I want to block ads using it, but I would have to manually add domains on it so I'm looking for some kind of work around?

I would prefer a solution that doesn't mean running something on my PC - because it's not on 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this with a DNS service. If you subscribe to [Alternate DNS](https://alternate-dns.com/), you may be able to get most of that done for you with very little configuration. Just have your router hand out their DNS server IPs, and you may be good to go.

To make use of their free service, just make these IP addresses the DNS servers on your router, and the ones handed out by DHCP:
198.101.242.72
23.253.163.53
These may change, so [check here](https://alternate-dns.com/setup.html) if you are looking well after this is published.

Alternatively, while probably not possible on your router (due to hardware lacking the required horsepower), Pi-Hole is a project that does exactly what you're looking for as an actual service running on your network. Others have done it differently. It can probably be adapted with very little work for a more powerful router running an open OS like Tomato, DD-WRT, OpenWRT, HyperWRT, Gargoyle, or ViOS ([Ubiquiti](https://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgerouter-lite/) devices are a great option). There are a lot of guides out there that could be adapted, and some purpose built stuff just for this. Check them out!

Pi-Hole:
https://pi-hole.net/

Adafruit Guide:
https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-as-an-ad-blocking-access-point/overview?view=all

Do a little research, and you'll find a lot of material on this.

Here are two DB references for your hardware:
[OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr941nd)
[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database)

Outside of that, if you're wanting to try and implement it on a router, I'd ask around on the respective support forums for those OS mentioned above. I would bet dollars to donuts there are power users that have done this already, just on something with a little beef.

Comment: I've created a OpenDNS but so far no option to add a host file, or copy and paste a large amount of domains so it can't work for this too...I'll check AlternateDNS

Comment: Oops! OpenDNS doesn't serve their own ads, but they don't block others. My bad

Comment: I removed OpenDNS from the answer, because it's not what you need.